# Terminal not displaying correctly after quitting Xorg

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, ati

I am running a fresh arch-linux install (as of 17/07/12) with the [ATI catalyst drivers](http://catalyst.apocalypsus.net/repo/catalyst/) (as mentioned on the wiki page).

When I run `xinit`, everything works fine and looks great but when I exit the xsession it doesn't return me to the standard bash terminal correctly. Instead I get what appears to be the top left quarter of the original terminal which is unresponsive apart from the occasional visual corruption when I press keys.

What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT:** Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> shows the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Had to add the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist radeon
```

It now closes X correctly, but i get the following warnings:

```
(WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:1:1) found
(WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:17:0) found
(WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:18:0) found
.... etc
```